# ODBC with oracle, bind numeric fields

Tags: c++, oracle, odbc

i have a big problem.
I use that functions for read type from db and binding the correct type in c++

```
SQLGetDescField(cursor->_desc,i,SQL_DESC_TYPE,&field->type,NULL,NULL)
```

that function with oracle tell me allway that the type is : SQL_DECIMAL
but it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see that for `VARCHAR` and `DATE` columns?

What do you see in schema information:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, 
decode(data_type,
    'DATE', '11',
    'NUMBER', data_precision || ',' || data_scale,
    data_length) data_length
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name='MY_TABLE' AND column_name = 'MY_COLUMN'
```

In ODBC I use `SQLColumns()` function to read schema information and using it you can retrieve (via RecordSet) type name and column size (various for various numeric types). Of course you can read such info directly from `user_tab_columns`. For numeric types just take care of `data_precision` and `data_scale`.

Comment: thanks but that wasn't the solution :S
That problem was that oracle fail to mapping correct datatype :S and the numbers were mapped in SQL_DECIMAL. I have fixxed with explicit type binding

Comment: I know it wasn't solution, but you haven't shown us database schema (as in `CREATE TABLE`) nor what type you would accept as correct for something reported as `SQL_DECIMAL`. I try to avoid typing so long SELECT in comment. With `SQLColumns()` all numeric types are reported as `SQL_DECIMAL`, but from your question it was not clear if `SQLGetDescField()` show it also for non-numeric types.